# How to mod color of active photo background on PicsArt.apk using APKstudio

Tags: android, colors, apk

I need some help in modding apk of PicsArt. I have trouble seeing my transparent pictures in this window [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xffVJ.jpg) that is the first editing mode when you entered PicsArt. I've successfully changed the background of number 1, as you can see, it was supposed to be dark/black but I changed it to this color code : `#eeeeee` the code was from colors.xml, you can find that in folder `res/value/colors.xml` then I changed it to `#eeeeee.`

Now I really need a help to change the color of number 2. FYI: it's not the picture that has color of black, but it's my transparent picture that shows in black color. I really hope someone could help me to change the color be like in the draw mode, you can see that window has checker-board pattern as the background.

Or if it's not possible it is alright for me to change just the color of it, example grey color.

I've tried myself to change and find some other color codes, but I keep failing to find and change that color. I'm using the latest version of PicsArt, you can download it for free on Play Store. I hope some experts in modding APK will come out and help me, it will be very helpful for me to make my work easier just using my phone.

EDIT : I've uploaded the colors.xml code somewhere [click here to see](https://shrib.com/?v=nc#SVeb_KpW.CAN0x6CMzAc) ,
but I dont think any of these code will work for the background colors that I've talked above, because I've tried to change every of it and I failed. I think it's somewhere else in the other folder that contains xml files. please help me

Comment: Your second image appears to be XML code. In order to help you, I guess people would want to copy and paste your XML so they can modify it to make suggestions on what to try. That is not possible with an image, so would you delete that image from your post and replace it with the XML as text instead? A code formatting tool is available.

Comment: @halfer I can't write the code there on the post. it's too long. it doesn't let me to post more than 30k characters. can you suggest me on where can I upload it?

Comment: It needs to be in the question. If you exceed the 30K limit, it is a good indicator that your question is too broad anyway. Cut it down so that it fits into the question please.